# Load ASM generated Class while runtime

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I wrote some Bytecode via ASM (The generated Class implements some known Interface).

I also have some dependencies on other classes.

Now I want to hook the byte array up into some Class.

How can I load the class from the byte array?

Right now I get NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: core/selecter/ObjectSelector/codegen/testClass.class

I use this Code to load the class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> SelectorAccess<T> createNewOrNull(byte[] bytesOfClass, String name) {
    try {
        return (SelectorAccess<T>) new ClassLoader() {
            public Class<?> defineClass(byte[] bytes) {
                return super.defineClass(name.concat(".class"), bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
        }.defineClass(bytesOfClass).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think it is because my ClassLoader doesnt know the dependencies of my class?

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: 1. Please always set a parent-classloader when defining a new classloader - also when you use `URLClassloader`, else it may lead to troubles later on (it might either not be able to find those dependencies or load them new - but class A loaded from CL1 != class A loaded from CL2 although the class is equal on byte-level!) 2. You should call `loadClass` on a CL to load a class and `defineClass` to load the bytes into memory (will be invoked by `loadClass`/`findClass` if it can't find the class in its cache or none of its parents know the definition yet.

Comment: which parent classloader should I use? Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ?

Comment: this depends on what CL loaded what classes. If you have a nested classloader architecture (f.e. a cl that contains shared classes and sub-CL which contain classes unique to a plugin f.e.) you need to pass the CL containing the shared classes as parent to the CL containing the plugin classes. If you do not have a nested architecture `getClass().getClassLoader()` might be enough, if you have a CL per thread, use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead

Comment: Well i am using  `getClass().getClassLoader()` and it does work. However this i going to be a Library, wouldnt it better to let the user decide which classloader he wants to use, what would the best default look like? `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` or `getClass().getClassLoader()`

Comment: why not specify the classloader to use as parameter? That way you are as flexible as possible. But if your library is always loaded by the application classloader at application start-time, `getClass().getClassLoader()` may be enough.

Comment: OK thanks. I will let the user decide what Classloader he wants to use. However the defaul will be `class.getClassLoader()` which will throw an exception when the given class could not be found anyway..

Answer (score 2):

Well, the exception points you to it: “IllegalName: core/selecter/ObjectSelector/codegen/testClass.class”. That’s not a legal class name as expected by [`ClassLoader.defineClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-):

> #### Parameters:
>
> name - The expected [binary name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#name) of the class, or `null` if not known

…

> #### Binary names
>
> Any class name provided as a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) parameter to methods in `ClassLoader` must be a binary name as defined by *The Java™ Language Specification*.
>
> Examples of valid class names include:
>
> ```
> "java.lang.String"
> "javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor"
> "java.security.KeyStore$Builder$FileBuilder$1"
> "java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1"
> ```

You get the picture, that method expects a dot-separated name without a `.class` suffix. I.e. if the class file internal name of your class really is `core/selecter/ObjectSelector/codegen/testClass`, the correct name for `defineClass` would be `core.selecter.ObjectSelector.codegen.testClass`.

However, note the mentioning of the possibility to simply pass `null` to the `name` parameter…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However @Roman Vottner already had a solution. My handgenerated bytecode had some dependencies which my custom classloader didnt load. After i used getClassLoader() everything worked as expected.

Comment: @user3858583: well, the dependencies are another issue but given the code of your question and the posted exception you never got that far as this one attempt to define a class was already rejected due to the illegal name before any dependencies came into play. If your new solution works, it implies that you have solved this issue as a side-effect. E.g., if you provide the byte code when requested by the JVM resolver, you’ll use the name requested by the JVM, most probably. And that name is, of course, the correct one.